# Facebook SDK 3.1 FacebookConnectPlugin.m 2 Deprecations

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, mobile, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm upgrade facebookSDK from 3.0 to 3.1 but I could not fix 2 deprecations...

1.
..../FacebookConnectPlugin.m:202:14: 'reauthorizeWithPermissions:behavior:completionHandler:' is deprecated

2.
..../FacebookConnectPlugin.m:248:14: 'openActiveSessionWithPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:' is deprecated

Does anyone have an idea?

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore this warning. With 3.1 you should split up read and publish permissions. For backwards compatibility, if you choose not to split this up you will go down the path of using the deprecated methods. If you only ask for reads or publish permissions separately, this code will not be called.